# numpy with cython, is it faster on large dataset-iterables?

Tags: list, performance, numpy, cython, processing-efficiency

I got lots of list-comprehensions, which would normally be a little faster if i used numpy arrays inplace of the sublists, but i plan on compiling it in cython in the end. 
Is it smarter using python lists instead of numpy in the code, when i plan to compile it in cython in the end anyways?
or
Do numpy arrays experience a speed up after compiling with cython or am i off with a better performance when i just use normal python lists? Is it proportional? ( I use very large datasets (half a million to multiple million elements or sublists))

some Examples how my list comprehensions look:

````
nextInt = 1
winPoints  = [[max(upSlice[:i])  for i in range(nextInt,len(upSlice)+1)] for upSlice in ppValues]```
````

```
def get_slice_max(arr, start):
    result = [max(arr[:start])]
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        result.append(max(result[-1], arr[i]))
    return result
winPoints  = [get_slice_max(upSlice, nextInt) for upSlice in ppValues]
```

```
winningRatio =[ [1 if ratioUp >ratioDown  else 0 if (ratioDown>ratioUp) else
                1 if (pointsUp>pointsDown) else 0 if (pointsDown>pointsUp) else 1   
                for ratioUp,ratioDown,pointsUp,pointsDown                  in  zip(ratioUpSlice,ratioDownSlice,pointsUpSlice,pointsDownSlice)] 
                for ratioUpSlice,ratioDownSlice,pointsUpSlice,pointsDownSlice in  zip(ratios_Up,ratios_Down, pointsUpSlices,pointsDownSlices)]
```

EDIT:
sorry i formulated the question ambiguos/wrong:

Does using numpy before running code via cython make any difference? And if so is this win on efficiency bigger than when using python lists and running in cython?

Comment: If you can use vectorized numpy functions, numpy should be significantly faster than Cython and CPython lists.

Comment: "I got lots of list-comprehensions, which would normally be a little faster if i used numpy arrays inplace of the sublists," No, *normally they wouldn't be*. Iteration at the interpreter level is *slowever* over numpy arrays than lists.

Comment: depending on the lenght of the sublist/subarray some actions are definetly faster. (for example: conditional replacements arr[arr>0] =  ... vs iterating over a python list and manually replacing.                                                                                          However, I added the following line to the question: "Does using numpy before running code via cython make any difference? And if so is this win on efficiency bigger than when using python lists and running in cython?"